# Posting large (40MB) MultipartFormDataContent to ASP.NET Core 3.1 returns 413 - RequestEntityTooLarge

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

This code:

```
var bytes = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(targetDir + "../deploy.release.zip"));
var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent {{bytes, "version", "deploy.release.zip" } };
var upload = await http.PostAsync($"{host}API/files/Upload/ENG", multiContent);
```

worked in ASP.NET Core 2.2 through Kestrel.

After upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3.1 and `InProcess` hosting model, I am getting (for 40MB file):

> 413 - RequestEntityTooLarge

I already set `requestFiltering`, but it doesn't help. My `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore 
          processPath="dotnet" 
          arguments=".\Web.Hosting.dll" 
          stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" 
          requestTimeout="23:00:00" 
          forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" 
          startupTimeLimit="3600" 
          hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="50374" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- Measured in Bytes 100MB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Did I miss something? Search on internet gives me result for WCF, old ASP.NET ...

I also try to add `<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />` but my application failed with 500.19.

**Edited:**

IIS recognize 100MB but uploading anything more then 20MB fails with 413.
[image: IIS]

Comment: Also set the maxRequestLength in the web.config (system.web ->httpRuntime -> maxRequestLength) do note this is in kb's whereas contentlenght is in bytes

Comment: Based on https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267 can you add the attribute [RequestSizeLimit(XXX)]  on one particular route to check if it improves the situation?

Comment: It doesn't help.